# converting buffer from C++ into utf-8 string in node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, buffer

I have server-side code written in C++ that returns a string. The client-side code is hosted in express. The client side code has calls endpoint as follows:

```
router.post( '/returnMyStringFromCPlusPlus', ( request, response ) => { 
    var returnedValue;
    try {
        var returnBuf = new Buffer.alloc( 512, 0 ); // this will fill buffer with 0
        returnedValue= serverSideCode.returnMyStringFromCPlusPlus();
         ... 
         }
```

When I get this returnedValue back, I see it is a buffer. I double-checked by testing:

```
     console.log(returnedValue instanceof buffer);
```

Which obviously returned true. The problem is I can't get that buffer into text! I've tried:

**String Decoder:**
            const StringDecoder = require( "string_decoder" ).StringDecoder;

```
        const decoder = new StringDecoder( "utf-8" )

        console.log( decoder.write( returnedValue) );
```

**toString():**

```
          console.log(returnedValue.toString('ascii'));
```

**String.fromCharCode**

```
           var printMe =  String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(returnCode));
           console.log(printMe)
```

Honestly I never really have had much luck *asking* questions on StackOverFlow and usually end up answering my own questions, but I'd be curious if any of you folks have seen this before. I have no clue how to solve this and have been doing it for over a day now.

**Questions I anticipate**

Using node version 11 (tried 12 and 13 as well)
Using x64 version of Visual Studio 
It shouldn't matter, but the code returned from C++ is literally:

```
   #include <string>
   string testThis()
    {
   string testIfThisWorks = "TestIfThisWorks";
   return testIfThisWorks;
   }
```

This is on Windows 10

Comment: You've mentioned that string should be in UTF-8. Have you tried `console.log(returnedValue.toString('utf8'));`?

Comment: Did you tried to print that Buffer? I mean value, not a type..

Comment: @igor.codes neither of these worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I know this is almost 7 months later, but I did eventually get back to finding a solution to this problem. I don't think it's ideal and am still open to better suggestions if I find one, but I found kind of a hacky way to do it. What I ended up doing was:

1. Passing in an argument from the client side node.js into the server side C++
2. Changing the value on the server side
3. Returning that same argument.

> ```
> router.post( '/returnMyStringFromCPlusPlus', ( request, response ) => { 
> var returnedValue;
> try {
>     var returnBuf = new Buffer.alloc( 512, 0 ); // this will fill buffer with 0
>     var valueToChange = "valueToChange";
>     returnedValue= serverSideCode.returnMyStringFromCPlusPlus(valueToChange);
>      ... 
>      }
> ```

I would then manipulate this value on the C side and return it as a string. <3